# Sharing rule based on condition

Tags: sharing

I have 3 sales rep under 1 manager. The Rep1 have created 3 opp today and need to be taken care on next day but due to some reason the Rep1 is on leave. Now we need to share 3 opp to Rep2. How can I achieve it dynamically.

Comment: Since this is an exception, could you just manually share these three?  or are you looking for a long-term solution?

Comment: No we need a automated process. Like when Rep1 apply for leave share the last created records with or (unclosed opp) with next rep2.

Comment: you should look at Apex Managed Sharing coupled with some simple VF page